# How to do push notificatoins on android - ionic 3 app without the need for firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3

I have an app that monitors changes on a server for a specific json response. But I would like this app to be able to check it periodically every 5-10 minutes and if something changes it should show a notification on my android phone. From my research it seems that most people use firebase service in order to do notifications.

Why can't my ionic 3 android app just use the phone to fetch the new data from the server directly in the background instead of using firebase? Is there a way to do it without a 3rd party service for ionic 3? I want to understand why one would want to use a 3rd party service vs doing it natively in the app.

And how would this be done when i want to compile my ionic 3 app to iOS for iPhone? Firebase or just natively?

Comment: you can use a background service to fetch.... firebase is used for the notifications. two different things here. i happen to use OneSignal. Firebase is basically GCM.

Comment: If i use a background service. doesnt my app have to be on all the time? What if I just rebooted my phone? how is onesignal better than firebase? i'd like to use something that i can work with iOS also.

Comment: well....firebase will work with ios also..... background services, you can limit it once a day, every hour, etc. in your service, you make a server to the server, if something changes, send out a notification. i just like onesignal because all they do is push. plus, im not using firebase, i use Parse-Server

Comment: but for the background service i have to open up my ionic app first right? otherwise it wont monitor anything. am i correct?

Comment: im not sure about ionic. whats it coded in? looks like js.

Comment: Firebase does not have anything to do with what you want to do. You want to create a sort of polling mechanism and thats not what firebase is for. Firebase is used so you dont waste the battery on the device by making network calls unnecessarily

Comment: yeah i dont want to waste battery on my users devices. polling is what i want but i also dont want to drain the battery neither. so i guess i have to use firebase?